# Best way to get next row based on primary key of any row in a table with sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
ID    Name    Sequence
--------------------------
45    Alex       1
22    John       2
2     Philip     3
65    Shine      4
356   Stephy     5
35    Tom        6
```

OK.. Here when I pass the ID 2 I should get the row of `Shine` since that's the next row based on the sequence after Philip (2)

Which is the best solution?

Comment: Downvoters please check the edit. Also I mentioned primary key in the title. So the ID column obviously unpredictable or random.. So I dont know what made them to downvote.. This is disappointing when someone posts something and some immediately downvoting..

Comment: Its not my `DV` but it will be better if you show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select top 1 t.*
from table t
where sequence > @id
order by sequence;
```

Comment: ID column is the primary key and so will be random. So we cant depend ID column... I didnt mentioned that in question..

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks for that... But downvoters are very quick most of the time.. I've got the answer.. Please have a look at it...

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1
    t.*
from
    myTable t
where
    sequence > @param
order by sequence
```

Comment: ID column is the primary key and so will be random. So we cant depend ID column... I didnt mentioned that in question unfortunately..

Answer (score -2):

I found an answer to my own question. It may be helpful for me such beginners but only available in  SQL 2012

> select * from (SELECT id,name,
>       LAG(id,1) OVER (ORDER BY sequence ) PrevID,LEAD(id,1) OVER (ORDER BY sequence ) NextID,sequence
>       FROM tbl) as mytable where previd=3

This will return

```
ID    Name    Sequence
--------------------------
65     Shine       4
```

Comment: This seems way over-complicated compared to the solutions that Mitch and I proposed.  (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks sir...  But honestly how can we depend on sequence column for that... since ID is totally random.. May be the row shine having a smaller ID than above sequence... So does those solutions work? Honestly Thats why I tried this LEAD way.. But honestly I dont know how Mitch's solutions works believing ID is always in order for sequence when where is 1000 of groups with each of them having sequence starting from 0

Comment: I suggest that you play with the different solutions on your data.  The `order by sequence` has quite similar behavior whether in a `lag()` or as a clause in a `select` query.